# Insert a video in tablelayout

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm trying to insert a video in a *tablelayout* but the activity is not running

Can anyone tell me what is wrong? Is there any way to do this if possible? thank you

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sang);

        tabLayout=(TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.layouttab);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Don du sang"));

        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("recepteur du sang"));
        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(R.drawable.hee);

        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(R.drawable.volunteering);
        pager=(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pagg);
        PagerAdapter pagerAdapter=new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),tabLayout.getTabCount());
        pager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

        pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                pager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

              /*  videoView=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.sauve);
                videoView.setVideoPath("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.sensibilisation);*/

            }
```